# Is it possible to have a modal button inside a foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a modal button inside a foreach loop with rows from a database, but i am only able to press the first button because it has the same value for each loop. I have been trying to use an increasing ID value `$i=0, $i++` but i can't get it to work.

```
foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM operation, OPuppgift where skift='natt' and klar='0' and operation.NR=OPuppgift.NR") as $row){
  $i++;
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$row['NR']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['kort_Uppgift']."
  </br>
    <button id=".$i." class='myBtn'>?</button>
    <div id=".$i." class='modal'>
      <div class='modal-content'>
        <span class='close'>&times;</span>
        <p>".$row['uppgift']."</p>
          <script type='text/javascript' src='modalJ.js'></script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>";
```

```
var modal = document.getElementById("1");
var btn = document.getElementById("1");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
};
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
};
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

Comment: why not possible??

Comment: You have a button _and_ a div with the same `id` attribute - not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the same ID for multiple objects. Your divs and buttons have the same ID, and are also not quoted.

Change this:

```
</br>
    <button id=".$i." class='myBtn'>?</button>
    <div id=".$i." class='modal'>
```

to this or something similar:

```
 </br>
    <button id='button".$i."' class='myBtn'>?</button>
    <div id='div".$i."' class='modal'>
```

Notice, I am prepending the ID number with a descriptor to differentiate between the buttons and the divs, and then using the same incrementing variable to ensure each pair gets the same number after the descriptor (eg: div1 goes with button1, etc).

You are also not enclosing the ID's in quotes. I enclose them in single quotes in my example revision above. The change will generate HTML output like this.

```
 </br>
    <button id='button1' class='myBtn'>?</button>
    <div id='div1' class='modal'>
...
 </br>
    <button id='button2' class='myBtn'>?</button>
    <div id='div2' class='modal'>
```

In your Javascript code, (thanks @kerbholz), change the IDs to match. I would do it programmatically (you're using a static value in your code), but, the end result should be prepending your designator like this (but via code that uses the correct number).

```
var modal = document.getElementById("div1");
var btn = document.getElementById("button1");
```

You're not passing the id number to your script though. You can use "this" or pass values, or other methods, so, your button controls the correct two elements.

Comment: Don't forget to change the javascript accordingly

Comment: Thanks @kerbholz for helping me improve my answer - I added comments pertaining to the Javascript.